# select distinct(col a) max(colb)

Tags: sql, date, max, distinct

I have a table with data similar to:

```
| col_a | col_b    |
|-------|----------|
|left   |01/01/2017|
|left   |02/02/2018|
|left   |03/03/2019| * 
|right  |04/04/2017|
|right  |05/05/2018|
|right  |06/06/2019| *
```

I am trying to extract data with the asterisks - ie the format below:

```
| col_a | col_b    |
|-------|----------|
|left   |03/03/2019|
|right  |06/06/2019|
```

I am using (pseudo code here - have alot of joins etc in the full command):

```
select distinct col_a, max(col_b) from table;
```

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `group by`

```
select col_a, max(col_b) from table
group by col_a
```